# vba - copy value from pivot if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a problem looping thru values of my pivottable. I want to check the value of the selected column ( inputbox ) and if its above 0.12, change the color of the cell and copy the value on the first column to another sheet.

Somehow the cell value of the column selected by the (inputbox ) is misread and the macro copies wrong ID's into the other sheet.

Details of the sheet: 
column A: ID ( needs to be copied to another sheet if condition is met ), 
Column B to M ( cells to be changed of color if > 0.12 )

Can you help me?

```
        Option Explicit

Sub mcruplift()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim rm As Integer


Dim result1 As Integer


Dim colmn As Integer
Dim weight As Integer


result1 = InputBox("welke maand wil je controleren? Waar wil je de controle starten?")

colmn = result1 + 1
i = 11
j = 3



Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, colmn)) = True Then

            weight = Cells(i, colmn).Value

                    Select Case weight

                        Case 0.12 To 0.17

                        Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 44

                                rm = Cells(i, 1)
                                Worksheets("Resultaat").Activate
                                Cells(j, 1) = rm
                                j = j + 1
                                Worksheets("sheet5").Activate

                        Case 0.17 To 0.25

                        Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 45

                                rm = Cells(i, 1)
                                Worksheets("Resultaat").Activate
                                Cells(j, 1) = rm
                                j = j + 1
                                Worksheets("sheet5").Activate

                        Case Is > 0.25

                        Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 46


                                rm = Cells(i, 1)
                                Worksheets("Resultaat").Activate
                                Cells(j, 1) = rm
                                j = j + 1
                                Worksheets("sheet5").Activate

                    End Select

            End If

i = i + 1

Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly!

Comment: Fully qualify your ranges. You are swopping sheets regularly and always  implicitly referencing the active sheet. Recipe for problems.

Comment: What happens if weight is <0.12 ? If you can specify this you can 
 potentially refactor your code and pull out the repeated 4 lines and put once after end select.

Comment: your integers should be Longs except weight should be Double.

Comment: And you have different colour settings and weights that are accepted for writing out your ID in your code versus only >.12  in your question

Answer (score 0):

So it is difficult to give a definitive answer on this due to all the unanswered questions I have posed in the comments. This can be tidied up but may move things forward. You should replace `Activesheet` with an explicit worksheet reference and ideally also ensure your are using the correct workbook.

1) You are not fully qualifying sheets whilst regularly changing sheets.

2) You have Integers which should be Longs to avoid  overflow and Integers which should be doubles to allow for correct condition evaluation.

3) You also state that only the > .12 weight should be coloured yet your code sample has a variety of different colour formats according to different weight categories.

4) Pivottables have a [databodyrange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-databodyrange-property-excel) property and you can specifically target columns - so other options include looping these or indeed, using a filter.

So, going out on a limb:

You might start with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mcruplift()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rm As Long
    Dim result1 As Long
    Dim colmn As Long
    Dim weight As Double

    result1 = InputBox("welke maand wil je controleren? Waar wil je de controle starten?") 'which month do you want to check? Where do you want to start the check?

    colmn = result1 + 1
    i = 11
    j = 3

    With ActiveSheet

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1))

            .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = vbNormal 'Clear out existing

            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, colmn)) Then

                weight = .Cells(i, colmn).Value

                Select Case weight

                Case 0.12 To 0.17

                    .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 44

                Case 0.17 To 0.25

                    .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 45

                Case Is > 0.25

                    .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 46


                End Select

                rm = .Cells(i, 1)

                Worksheets("Resultaat").Cells(j, 1) = rm

                j = j + 1

            End If

            i = i + 1

        Loop

    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate

End Sub
```

And more closely matching your stated objective:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mcruplift()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rm As Long
    Dim result1 As Long
    Dim colmn As Long
    Dim weight As Double

    result1 = InputBox("welke maand wil je controleren? Waar wil je de controle starten?") 'which month do you want to check? Where do you want to start the check?

    colmn = result1 + 1
    i = 11
    j = 3

    With ActiveSheet

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1))

            .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = vbNormal 'Clear out existing

            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, colmn)) And .Cells(i, colmn) > 0.12 Then

                .Cells(i, colmn).Interior.ColorIndex = 44

                rm = .Cells(i, 1)

                Worksheets("Resultaat").Cells(j, 1) = rm

                j = j + 1

            End If

            i = i + 1

        Loop

    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this usefull comment! I helped me a lot.

Comment: pleased to have helped. Hope you solved it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *looping* though your PivotTable, *filter* it on the condition you want, change the color of all cells of interest in one go, and copy those cells to the other sheet in one go.

Fire up the macro recorder to get the syntax of the filter. And to get the syntax on how to reference parts of a PivotTable, refer to Jon Peltier's excellent article:
https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/